# Re-parenting large objects in Unity takes up to 8 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this scenario where I need to make root of a very large hierarchy child of Oculus Hand, and it takes up to 8 seconds, depending on how large that hierarchy is.

Here is sample code:

```
//On new model import. 1108 is default hand hierarchy capacity
rightHand.hierarchyCapacity = 1108 + 2 * importedModel.transform.hierarchyCapacity;


private void Update()
{
   if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))
      importedModel.transform.SetParent(Coordinator.instance.rightHand);    
   else if (OVRInput.GetUp(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))
      importedModel.transform.SetParent(null);
}
```

Is there an optimised way of re-parenting large objects? I have seen many solutions on Unity forum, but none of those address my scenario.

Comment: Are you sure it is comming from the SetParent function? Is that what the profiler says?
Have you tried disabling any rigidbodies/ triggers before changing the parent? Does it make any difference?

Comment: It's coming exactly from SetParent only

Answer (score 2):

## There may not be much you can do, but...

Transform hierarchies are stored in memory by Unity as *fixed sized arrays* and reparenting causes Unity to have to recompute the *entire modified hierarchy* to move things around in memory to create enough room and then insert the new objects. There's a Unity talk video on YouTube about this, if I can find it. This may sound like a terrible plan on Unity's part, but its the result of a different optimization that allows Unity to process the entire hierarchy as a linear list and using simple offsets down in the C++ backend.

Your best bet is to tell Unity "hey, this object, I want extra space in its hierarchy array" enough to fit the objects you're going to be moving into it. The key thing here is that you have to do this as early as you can. Doing it just before you reparent stuff isn't really going to help, as Unity will be performing this operation at that point anyway.

You can do this by setting the value of [`Transform.hierarchyCapacity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hierarchyCapacity.html) to a large enough value. However, my experience with using this property is that predicting the needed size is an exercise in frustration. For the same number of objects I was inserting I was getting different desired capacities from Unity and I ended up just having to over-estimate wildly.

Comment: Looked exactly same issue to me, but didn't help, since hand hierarchy capacity should be an issue only first time we are making entire model a child of it. Next time onward it should be fine. Can there by anything else mysterious going on? I am only doing `SetParent`, nothing else.

Comment: Certainly could be, the problem is that the details are down inside the Unity engine and it may not be possible to resolve the issue in your case.